# Error while installing with composer

Tags: composer-php, yii2, twilio

I am getting error while installing package for Yii2 from https://github.com/bryglen/yii2-twillio. Composer says "The requested package could not be found in any version". What can be the problem? Is there another option to install this package?

Here is detailed description of my composer.json https://github.com/bryglen/yii2-twillio/issues/1

Comment: Did you run `composer global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:~1.0.0"`

See [the guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-start-installation.html#installing-via-composer).

Comment: Yes, I ran this code in the very beginning as it is described in the guide. Otherwise I guess I could not install many other extensions, that I already installed successfully. Right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you have your composer config "minimum-stability" set to "stable", while your package does not have stable version.
Try to require the package with --dev option.

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking about it, but did not try yet. Moreover in config compoents must have class 'bryglen\twillio\Twillio', not as it is described.